# Why type inference is not able to infer a type in a function callback?

Tags: dart

I have a class:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  final void Function(T) bar;
  Foo(T t, {required this.bar});
}
```

and I'm passing `int` value so that `T` can be inferred as `int`, but the issue is in the following code, `t` is of type `Object?` and not `int`. Why is that so?

```dart
Foo(0, bar: (t) {
  // `t` is of type `Object?`
});
```

**Note**: I'm not looking for a solution, which is to use `Foo<int>(0, bar: ...)`. I want to know the reason why `t` is not inferred correctly

Comment: When I try your code in DartPad (which as of writing is based on Dart SDK 2.15.1), the `Foo` object is inferred to be a `Foo<int>` and not as `Foo<Object?>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I think there was some confusion. I'm using IDE, so the autocompletion is showing `t` is of type `Object?` but when you print `t.runtimeType`, then it is of type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you describe should now be fixed as of Dart 2.18.

### Original answer for earlier versions of Dart

Your problem can be more clearly observed with:

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  final void Function(T) bar;
  Foo(T t, {required this.bar});
}

Type staticType<T>(T object) => T;

void main() {
  var foo = Foo(0, bar: (x) => print(staticType(x)));

  print(staticType(foo)); // Prints: Foo<int>
  print(staticType(foo.bar)); // Prints: (int) => void
  print(foo.bar.runtimeType); // Prints: (Object?) => void
  foo.bar(42); // Prints: Object?
}
```

I'm not an expert on the inference rules, but (prior to Dart 2.18) inference either could flow top-down (from function to arguments) or bottom-up (from arguments to function).  Since you don't supply an explicit type parameter when constructing `Foo`, `Foo`'s generic type argument `T` must be inferred from its arguments.  However, the argument type to the anonymous function also isn't specified, so it's assumed to be `Object?`.

For `Foo`'s `T` to be inferred as `int` *and* for the anonymous function to be inferred to be `(int) => void` would require inference to flow from the positional argument up to the function and back down to the named argument, [which Dart (prior to 2.18) did not do](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731).  You thus instead ended up with the `(Object?) => void` anonymous function being implicitly cast to `(int) => void`.

Comment: Indeed, when on DartPad I switch from Dart 2.17 to Dart 2.18, the error disappears. However, I upgraded my Flutter's Dart SDK to 2.18 on my computer, and I still had this kind of error.  In case this helps anyone: I fixed this by also upgrading the required Dart SDK version in the `pubspec.yaml` file.